# How to slice an array in a custom pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this array:

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,"a","b","c",9,10];
```

**I would like to slice this array into this pattern:**

```
var x = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,"a"],[5,"a","b"],["a","b","c"],["b","c",9],["c",9,10]];
```

I used the following code and been able to get `[[1,2,3],[4,5,"a"],["b","c",9],[10,11,12]]` . But it doesn't work for me. I need to get the pattern above.

```
var stream = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
var ad_time = 6;
var result = [];

var ad_index = stream.indexOf(ad_time);

if (~ad_index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        stream[ad_index + i] = x[i];
    }
}

while (stream.length > 0) {
    var chunk = stream.splice(0, 3);
    result.push(chunk);

}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Thanks in advence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with a simple `for` loop:

```js
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,"a","b","c",9,10];
var result = [];

for (var i = 0, il = x.length - 2; i < il; i++) {
    result.push([x[i], x[i + 1], x[i + 2]]);
}

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT:** [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is more elegant, however it is much slower. On Chrome it is 80% - 85% slower according to [this](http://jsperf.com/direct-access-vs-slice) test. If you don't need to worry about performance, choose whichever you like. For example if you need to slice 8 elements from the array, then using `x.slice(i + 8)` is easier to write and read than `[x[i], x[i + 1], x[i + 2], x[i + 3], ...]`. However if performance matters, then direct access might be a better choice.

Comment: You're a genius... Thank you! But.. I guess Daniel's solution looks more elegant?

Comment: @scaryguy Yes, `Array.slice()` is more elegant, however it is much slower than direct access. See this test: http://jsperf.com/direct-access-vs-slice

Comment: Because of this performance difference, I'm accepting your answer Gergo. Can you add this note about performance to your answer? Comments may not be seen by everyone. Thanks!

Comment: @scaryguy Sure, added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This code should do it:

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,"a","b","c",9,10];

var new_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length - 2; i++) {
    new_array.push(x.slice(i, i + 3));
}
```

Comment: Wow! Can you please explain it? How you've found this solution?

Comment: @scaryguy It's rather elementary. Loop all elements except the last two since you want groups of three. If you wanted groups of 4 you needed to subtract 3 from the length of the array. During each pass store a copied slice of the original array based upon the index with a length of `3` in an new array.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for answer but see the link Gergo has given at his comment. This solution is almost 7 times slower than his solution. Although your answer seems more elegant, to take other readers' attention, I'm accepting his answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mouser, thanks for explanation. I would upvote your comment if it didn't start with that despising sentence.